# Does Flask-Bootstrap wtf.quick_form render SelectFields?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Hello Python Flask Experts:

I need help with rendering a form using `wtf.quick_form`

I am trying to publish a registration form having user name, password and a role field.
User name and Password are straight forward text fields.
Role is a select field.

My form looks like this

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    yourName = StringField('Your Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    empId = StringField('Employee ID')
    roleChoices = ('Manager', 'Stores', 'Sales', 'Engineer', 'QC', 'Vendor')
    desiredRole = SelectField('Desired Role', choices=[(roleChoices, roleChoices)], default=1)
    submit = SubmitField(_l('Register'))
```

And my Register.html looks like this

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}
    <h1>{{ _('Register') }}</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

But, the output is not rendering the select field as a drop down.
It is showing just one item `('Manager', 'Stores', 'Sales', 'Engineer', 'QC', 'Vendor')` and selecting it as shown in the image below.

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr9H6.png)

I consulted the WTForms documentation available at https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/forms.html.

Looks like only text fields are rendered? Or have I made a any mistakes?

Comment: Quick question for you: What is the output for: 
print(roleChoices)??

Comment: Got it! I wasn't forming the choices properly.

Comment: Try adding your fix as the answer :D

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer:

I was not forming the answer choices properly.

```
desiredRole = SelectField('Desired Role', choices=[(roleChoice, roleChoice) for roleChoice in roleChoices], default=1)
```

Now, the code output is rendering Select fields.